# Where are the Xcode 'prepackaged' images stored?

Tags: xcode, uitextfield

I need access to the image of the default clear button that apple provides because I want to use it somewhere else in my app, where can I find the image file? If apple doesn't allow access to them, does anyone have a link to this image, i've been searching for a while now and haven't found a proper .png image i can use (I don't have photoshop, so I can't edit them myself).

The image I'm talking about is the one that shows up if i add this line of code:

```
textfield.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to use this. http://www.teehanlax.com/tools/iphone/
It's a psd, but you should be able to extract the ressource using a tool like acorn.

Ok, I was feeling nice: [image: the asset]

Comment: you answered it so fast it wouldn't let me, had to wait 3 minutes :)